# Github Actions error configuring Terraform AWS Provider

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the error below using the Terraform AWS Provider when trying to run `terraform plan`. This only happens when running on GitHub Actions (it works fine locally)

> error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: failed to get shared config profile

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.22"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.7"
}
```

If I downgrade to `version = "~> 3.0"` it fixes the problem. But I would like to upgrade to the latest version.

Is there a way to make this run on CI?

Comment: How are you authenticating for AWS in GH Actions?

Comment: @MattSchuchard - Ahh, you're exactly right. Just figured it out. I'll post answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the solution

In the GitHub Actions file, we had something like:

```
# Provides AWS credentials to Terraform
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-region: us-east-1
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.YOUR_ACCESS_KEY }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

I had to remove this and change it to authenticate through `aws configure` as seen below:

```
- name: Add profile credentials to ~/.aws/credentials
  run: |
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${{ secrets.YOUR_ACCESS_KEY }} --profile test-1
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${{ secrets.YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} --profile test-1
```